# Writing a file line by line in C

Tags: c, input, output

I'm currently trying to get my code to write data to file exactly the way it prints it.
For some reason, when I open the textfile afterwards there is only binary data.
How do I get that to a readable format?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calcData(float *x,float* y){
    float tmpX,tmpY,a,b;
    a = 2.75;
    b = 0.2;
    tmpX = *x;
    tmpY = *y;
    *x = tmpY;
    *y = (-b*tmpX) + (a*tmpY) - (tmpY*tmpY*tmpY);
    return;
}

int main(){

    FILE *datei;
    float x = 0.5;
    float y = 0.5;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
        calcData(&x,&y);
        printf("%f \t %f \n",x,y);
        datei=fopen("txt.txt","a");
        fwrite(&x,1,sizeof(float),datei);
        fwrite("\t",1,sizeof(char),datei);
        fwrite(&y,1,sizeof(float),datei);
        fwrite("\n",1,sizeof(char),datei);
        fclose(datei);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `fprintf`– just like you use `printf`.

Comment: "write data to file exactly the way it prints it" . What does that mean?  What's the difference between writing to the file and printing to the file.  The "way it prints"  is exactly the same as "the way it writes".

Comment: Another way is to redirect the program output, for example `myprogram > txt.txt`

Comment: OT: regarding: `float x = 0.5;` and `float y = 0.5;` and `a = 2.75;` and `b = 0.2;`  the literals being declared are `doubles`, not `floats`  To make then `floats`, each literal must contain a trailing `f`, Example: `0.2f`

Answer (score 6):

> when I open the textfile afterwards there is only binary data.

because doing

> ```
>    fwrite(&x,1,sizeof(float),datei);
>    ..
>    fwrite(&y,1,sizeof(float),datei);
> ```

you write the internal representation of the floats.

For instance the first couple of values is x=0.500000 and y=1.150000, their internal representation are 0x3f000000 and 0x3f933333 (IEEE floats are on 32b). So when you *fwrite* the 4 bytes of memory supporting their value depending on the *endianness* you write the codes 0x3f 0x0 0x0 0x0 for *x* and 0x3f 0x93 0x33 0x33 for *y* of them in the reverse order

> How do I get that to a readable format?

do

```
fprintf(datei, "%f\t%f\n", x, y);
```

in the same way you did `printf("%f \t %f \n",x,y);`

(Note that `printf("%f \t %f \n",x,y);` is in fact `fprintf(stdout, "%f \t %f \n",x,y);` , so if this is the right way on the standard output it is also in a file)

It is also better to move `datei=fopen("txt.txt","a");` *before* the loop and `fclose(datei);` *after* the loop